# Javascript: Filter array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

What am I doing wrong here?

```js
var locations = [
        { id: 1, name: 'N'},
        { id: 2, name: 'P'}
    ]

var employee = { location_id: 1 }

locations.filter((location) => {
    return location.id == employee.location_id
});

console.log(locations);
```

this returns `undefined` when I'm trying to make it return `{ id: 1, name: 'N'}`.

Comment: This code works well to me.

Comment: This code certainly does not produce `undefined` in any way. So if you get that, you must be doing something very different.

Comment: It actually returns an array with the object. Try to use `Array.prototype.findIndex` to get index of the object in the array.

Comment: well filter does not change the original array....

Comment: The only thing I removed was the scope of the variables so maybe thats where I'm going wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`filter()` function is not *mutable* - which means it returns a *new* array with the *filtered* objects and do *not* 'mutate' the original array - you must assign it to another variable - see demo below:

```js
locations = [
    { id: 1, name: 'N'},
    { id: 2, name: 'P'}
]

employee = { location_id: 1 }

var result = locations.filter((location) => {
    return location.id == employee.location_id
})

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a variable for the result of filtering with [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

> The **`filter()`** method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

```js
var locations = [
        { id: 1, name: 'N'},
        { id: 2, name: 'P'}
    ],
    employee = { location_id: 1 },
    result = locations.filter((location) => {
        return location.id == employee.location_id
    });

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the result of [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter). It doesn't  mutate the original array.

---

On a side note, you can shorten your callback function by removing the curly brackets and return statement.

```
locations = locations.filter(loc => loc.id == employee.location_id);
```